# how do i change and display results of select counting query when i click on different categories?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, count

how do i change and display results of select counting query when i click on different categories? i have query and that is working for me and given me results how many added items in each categories.

but i want to change `counting results` when i click on each categories?

**Counting  Query**

```
<?php  
$querycount=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM products GROUP BY cid") 
or die ("Product Count Query");
$rowcount=mysql_fetch_array($querycount);
echo $rowcount['count']?>
```

**For Example I Want Like This**

there are two categories in the mysql database

```
1) Jeans  // when i click on jeans it should be display  (10 items) 
2) Shirts // when i click on shirts it should be display (20 items)
```

now how do i change `results` when the category page changed?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and you want to get a count for one category, add a where clause into you sql statement, For example

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM products 
WHERE cid=123
```

Comment: @lan i have tried before but it is not working `$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM products WHERE cid='$id'  GROUP BY cid`

Comment: @lan `cid` is categories id

Comment: $id=$_REQUEST['id']; $qry="select count(*) as count from products where cid = $id" ; $querycount=mysql_query( $qry ) ....

Comment: @lan thanks it working now can you resolve my this issue 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164437/i-cant-unset-session-properly-onclick-remove-button/16165093?noredirect=1#16165093

i want to resolve it soon as possible and also on urgent based? please if you can help me out thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i understand you either.
have you tried SELECT ing the catergory you want.

as in

```
$sql= SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = jeans/shirts

$result =  mysql_query($sql) or die ('fail');
```

then put that result into array of rows. and count the rows.

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

if you want a link that you click on you can use:

```
<a href="index.php?category=jeans">Jeans</a>

<a href="index.php?category=shirts">shirts</a>
```

errr then you'd have to change your query to be:

```
$category = $_GET['category'];

$sql= SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = '$category'
```

oh and of course:

```
echo $num_rows;
```

don't quote me 100% on the code, i've recently converted over to `PDO` and kinda forgotten the old`mysql` ways. Something which you need to do aswell.

Comment: thanks it working now can you resolve my this issue stackoverflow.com/questions/16164437/… i want to resolve it soon as possible and also on urgent based? please if you can help me out thanks in advance –